# \begin{sloppypar} works but TeXstudio complains

Tags: texstudio, sloppy

I have the following warning on TeXstudio:

[image]

But everything works correctly - adding the `\begin{sloppypar}` & `\end{sloppypar}` helped my URL to properly breakdown instead of sticking out on the right of my paragraph.

Comment: Don't worry about what texstudio says. Texstudio does not actually know anything about tex, it just compares your input with a list of words defined in cwl files. If you want texstudio to recognise it, you could add it to your own cwl file

Comment: A better way to break urls is to load the `xurl` package

Comment: What would I add to my cwl file?

Comment: Ima look up xurl thanks

Comment: Something like `\begin{sloppypar}#` and `\end{sloppypar}` should do in your user .cwl file

Comment: See https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands for a bit of background information

Comment: I've added to `user.cwl` the following line `\begin{sloppypar}#\end{sloppypar}` and stored it in `C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\completion\user\user.cwl` but nothing changed?

Comment: a) You need to place them on separate lines b) check in your tex studio preferences the "Completion" tab if there is a checkmark for user.cwl c) close and reopen texstudio (no idea if the location is correct, I'm not a windows user)

Comment: I did a) and b) and it now works, cheers!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: For the record, texstudio chooses not to automatically recognize commands listed in the [l2tabu](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu) document, which includes `sloppypar`. You can override this by checking `latex-l2tabu.cwl` in the completion menu.

Comment: @mbert is `sloppypar` obsolete?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows I'm not sure obsolete is the right word, but you can read about the issues on pages 8-9 of [`l2tabu`](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf) (it's in German, the English translation has not been updated recently)